# .NET Core AppSettings.json - Get the right class for a derived item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, appsettings

I'm trying to get the parameter from my appsettings.json which is a list of derived classes.
The problem is that I don't know how I can retrieve the information and create the object with the good class for each item get.

My appsettings.json is something like this :

```
"DiagnosticSettings": {
"Diagnostics": [
  {
    "Type": "Connection",
    "Address": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "Type": "DNS",
    "DNSAddress": "www.google.com",
    "IPToCompare": "8.8.8.8"
  },
  {
    "Type": "DNS",
    "DNSAddress": "www.abc.com",
    "IPToCompare": "x.x.x.x"
  }, [...] 
]}
```

I have a base class :

```
public class BaseDiagnosticConfig
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And derived classes like :

```
public class DNSDiagConfig : BaseDiagnosticConfig
{
    public string DNSAddress { get; set; }
    public string IPToCompare { get; set; }
}
```

I can retrieve the provider which contains the list of items with something like this :

```
var a = Configuration.GetSection("DiagnosticSettings:Diagnostics");
```

And I can have the list of base class (but it is not what I want as I lost all the derived classes information) :

```
var b = Configuration.GetSection("DiagnosticSettings:Diagnostics").Get<List<BaseDiagnosticConfig>>();
```

So there is a way to get my items which the good class even if I had to check one by one all the items in my appsettings list or I am just doing something impossible/wrong ?

Comment: You are paddling against the stream here, what not use a list of class with a property called Type, and a dictionary of attributes? or even make it all just a dictionary with dictionary of attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do like this. I am providing you a very simple example, you can use according to your requirement.

```
"MySettings": {  
    "Email": "abc@domain.com",   
  }


public class MySettingsModel  
{   
       public string Email { get; set; }  
}
```

Register it

```
services.Configure<MySettingsModel>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

Declare in the class in which you want to read the setting.

```
private readonly IOptions<MySettingsModel> appSettings; 
public StudentController(IOptions<MySettingsModel> app)  
{  
    appSettings = app;  
}
```

Read the value

```
var value = appsettings.Value;
```

Reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-values-from-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core/